# Copy and Pasting a Moving Range in Google Sheets

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, copy-paste

I'm very much still learning the basics of script writing, but I have a rather specific question that I've not been able to find a solution for - perhaps because I might be phrasing it wrong.

Essentially, In sheet `MS`, I have a range of data (`A2:O23`) with formulas that I want to stay fixed (as in, always reference the same range in a different sheet).

My aim is, at the run of a script, that this block of formulas will copy and paste from the next empty row (in the same columns [`A:O`]) and that the previous block (`A2:O23`) will copy and paste over itself as values.

Then, each time the script runs, it does the same thing, copying the latest block of 22 rows beneath itself and pasting itself as values. Essentially having the effect of building a long list of data with the latest (read lowest) range being the formulas and all above being values.

For example, the results of the first time it runs should be that, `A24:O45`now show the same formula and that `A2:O23` are showing as values only. The next time, `A24:O45` would be frozen as values and `A46:O67` are now the formulas.

I'm not sure if this requires the use of loops or there is a different way to achieve the effect, but the former is something I've not used and the latter is still a mystery to me.

I realise that this might not be especially clear, but I'm happy to field any questions and greatly appreciate any efforts made to help.

Thanks

Comment: So you wan't a script to copy that last 22 rows to the next 22 rows.  Is that it?

Comment: To a point. I suppose it makes sense to look at it in two parts, or to break it into two functions even.

The first would be to copy the previous range, which as you say is 22 rows (and 16 columns), down.

The second part would be to then copy the previous range and paste it over itself as values, so it's no longer formulas and cannot change when the source data does.

I hope that makes a bit more sense, but appreciate the interest

Comment: Okay I think I understand.  You wan't to copy the last 22 rows and paste then as formulas in the next 22 rows and then paste on top of themselves as values.  And that's all you want right.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I think I just phrased it poorly.

Comment: Do you have 22 rows of formulas to test it with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to:

- Copy the last 22 rows of your sheet (columns `A` to `O`) to the next 22 rows (formulas included).
- Copy/paste to the original range as values only.

If the above is correct, then you can copy and run the following code to the script bound to your spreadsheet (see inline comments for detail on what the code is doing, step by step):

```js
function copyPasteValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MS"); // Name of your sheet (change if that's necessary)
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var firstCol = 1; // First column to copy
  var numCols = 15; // Number of columns to copy
  var numRows = 22; // Number of rows to copy
  if (lastRow > numRows) { // Check if the sheet has at least 23 rows with content (otherwise it would give error when copying the range)
    var originRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow - numRows + 1, firstCol, numRows, numCols);
    var destRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, firstCol, numRows, numCols);
    originRange.copyTo(destRange); // Copying with formulas to next 22 rows
    originRange.copyTo(originRange, {contentsOnly:true}); // Copying only values to same range
  }
}
```

The main method to notice here is `copyTo`, which can be used to copy the data as it is, [with formulas included](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination), or [values only](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options), by setting the parameter `{contentsOnly:true}` ([copyValuesToRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyvaluestorangegridid,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend) could be used too).

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Lamblichus. I've had a go with it and it doesn't seem to change anything, which is odd as it makes perfect sense to me (especially the notes, which are great for learning). You've understood the issue correctly too. It may be that my explanation was a little off, in which case, I'm happy to share the doc with you, if that would help find the issue?

Comment: @Geg Is your sheet named `MS`? If that's not the case, please change the name to yours in the code I provided.

Comment: @Geg that's strange because I tried it and it's working for me. Is the script bound to your spreadsheet? If that's the case, please consider sharing a copy of the spreadsheet (free of sensitive information) so that I can try to reproduce this.

Comment: @Geg Make sure there are no rows with content after the data you want to copy (in the sample you shared, for example, the green cell with the message `Paste the formulas here` is gonna mess up with the script). And if you log the last row with content with the script, it returns index 346 (there must be some content in that row). To be sure, please delete all rows after 23 and create them again (just clearing them is not working). Also, as I saw, if you only want columns A o O, `numCols` should be `15` instead (changed it in my response). (copying column P was also giving problems)

Answer (score 0):

```
function copypastepaste() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rows=sh.getLastRow();
  if(rows>22) {
    var rg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()-21,1,22,16);
    var vA=rg.getDisplayValues();
    var fA=rg.getFormulas();
    var nrg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,22,16);
    nrg.setFormulas(fA);
    rg.setValues(vA);
  }      
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper. Thanks for this, but unfortunately, it doesn't appear to change anything. In answer to your previous comment, yeah, there are currently 22 rows pulling through data. It's these rows that I want to overwrite as values after having copied the formulas to the cells below. I think the problems are related to my explanations. Would it help if I shared access to the doc with you?